# Mac - Mounted volume access to multiple users on mac, or intelligent link in OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac

I'd like to mount a samba share to /NAS/Photos in a way that's accessible to all users via fast user switching. Home PC/Network, multiple family members.

I can't find any way of mounting that is accessible to more than one user, which was my first port of call - seems impossible in Mavericks, although possible in older versions maybe.

**Take 1**

Mounting via /etc/auto_master:

> /NAS              auto_smb    -nosuid,noatime

With /etc/auto_smb:

> Pi  -fstype=smbfs,soft,noatime    ://xxxx:xxxx@192.168.1.82/NAS1000GB

Has the following output from mount:

> //xxxx@192.168.1.82/NAS1000GB on /NAS/Pi (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, noatime, nobrowse, mounted by steve)

Essentially it gets mounted by first user to access it, and then the other users don't have access.

ls -l

> drwx------  1 steve  wheel  16384 29 Jan 12:33 PiSteve

**Take 2**

> mount -o soft,noatime,nosuid -t smbfs  //xxxx:xxxx@192.168.1.82/NAS1000GB/Photos ~/PiNAS

Has the same issue, mounted by the first person to access it, with only that user having access

> //pies@192.168.1.82/NAS1000GB/Photos on /Users/steve/PiNAS (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, noatime, mounted by steve)

**Take 3**

Next option was for each user to mount separately /NAS/PhotsUser1 and /NAS/PhotosUser2 so access is ok, but I then need a way to link this to /NAS/Photos for both users so that applications such as Lightroom can find the photos.

Any ideas or alternative approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: How were you mounting it? In what way was it inaccessible to other users? Did you look into ownership/permissions/ACL problems? How about user ID and group ID mismatches?

Comment: Yes, I spent a fair while looking at that. It appears that with OSX Mavericks it's not possible to mount and give permissions to another user. I've tried mount command with every option I can see (many of which aren't implemented in the osx mount) and mounting through /etc/auto_master. Are you aware a way that might work?

Comment: I was hoping you could describe it in more detail, such as "on the server, it has UID x, GID y, and permissions x-y-z; when I mount it via {example mount command line}, from my account with UID a and default GID b it shows up on the Mac as owned by UID c, GID d, and permissions e-f-g." That would give a lot more insight into what's happening on your system.

Comment: Added some more detail in the question, but not sure exactly what you're after. Thanks

Comment: What you added gives a much clearer picture. Does your Samba server (NAS box?) give you shell access? It would be interesting to see what user and group IDs, and what permissions (such as "755" or "rxwr-xr-x") these files and directories have on the server's disk's native filesystem (as opposed to how they're getting translated by the SMB protocol and your Mac). Try adding `-d 777 -f 777` to your arguments to `mount`, to make sure everyone can read and write everything. See `mount_smbfs(8)` for more information.

Comment: I tried this for a long time on 10.6 or 10.8, and eventually gave up.  Apple's AFP and SMB implementations do not seem to support this.  I think NFS supports it better, but I couldn't get that to work reliably.  Could be my NAS box, but seems like you're having the same problems.  You might not be able to make it work at this low of a level, and instead use an Apple-approved solution, like setting up a Photostream from one account, and letting the other users (local or remote) subscribe to it.

Answer (score -1):

I hate to say this, but rather than going through the command line.  Have you just tried adding the volume to the users login items under System preferences/Users & Groups.  I used that method a few years ago.

Comment: Yes, it has much the same effect. The second user can't view the volume the 1st user has mounted. If the second user then opens the same location, another volume is created with XXXXX-1 at the end. This means locations are different between the different users, which I'd like to avoid as lightroom, etc can't cope with that.

Comment: Okay, so I was curious about this and found this article.

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57531358-263/mount-network-shares-privately-in-os-x/

It lets you mount a volume privately so it only shows up for one user.  They are not mounted in the root volumes folder, so you should not have the naming issue.  Good luck.